# Does China always issue a 2 year tourist visa for British citizens?

Tags: visas, china, uk-citizens

I'm going to China in March 2020 (visa pending), I'd rather just get the visa, hotels, insurance etc sorted out the way as soon as possible so I don't have to worry about it later.

I've read sometimes China issues the visa date when they process it. So if it's a 2 year one that's fine as as it will go till 2021, but if it's only like 3 months or something I'd have to get a new one closer to the date.

Anyone have any recent experience or know for sure if it's a 2 year multiple entry visa? Or should I just wait closer to the trip?

I can't use the 144 hour visa free transit, due to leaving and coming back in via train at a port that doesn't count towards it.

Comment: If you applied for the visa and gave details of your trip, specifying that it's in March 2020, and they did want to issue a short visa, surely they'd issue it just for that period, and not starting now?

Comment: @JoeMalt Yeah I get that, but i've read sometimes they just issue it from when they process it, don't know if they just make mistakes or it's intentional.

Comment: @BritishSam At least for the short term visas (non-tourist) I've had, it was intentional. The advice was to apply between 3 and one months before travel. I have no idea about type L though.

Comment: Thanks @origimbo, i think i'll just sort everything out and wait for the new year for the visa, they want you to have hotel and insurance etc before you apply anyway.